# angular.module called from separate files, does not find Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, angularjs-controller, controllers

I am trying to modularize my code and moved controller in a separate file that uses same module. But, it does not load, I made sure the load order is correct.

```
// app.js
angular.module("app", []);

// LoginCtrl.js
angular.module("app", []).controller("LoginCtrl", function() 
{
  //doSomeThing
});
```

If I do var app = angular.module in first file and use the same variable in other files, it works.

```
// app.js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

// LoginCtrl.js
app.controller("LoginCtrl", function() 
{
  //doSomeThing
});
```

If I move all code in one file and use angular.module separately for each component, it works.

```
// app.js
angular.module("app", []);

angular.module("app", []).controller("LoginCtrl", function() 
{
  //doSomeThing
});
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a module in AngularJS:
`angular.module('app', []);`

To get a module in AngularJS:
`angular.module('app');`

You use the same signature in your code to create and get a module, you mustn't add the injection array as the second argument of the module function when getting a module in another file.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I made he changes and verified it, working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,there can be only one module in a controller.                                         This is an example                                                                                                                 var app = angular.module('myApp', [])                         .controller('Controllername', function () {};

Answer (score -1):

After modulerizing your code, write this in your LoginCtrl.js file:

```
var app = angular.module("app");
app.controller("LoginCtrl", function() {
...
```

Comment: I prefer using the daisy-chain pattern here, instead of create a new variable.

Comment: Hi Sidharth, I don't want to use app variable. There was a typo, I was passing the injection array always and it was re-initializing the module at each page. Check Ripley511's answer.

Comment: Not sure why this received a down vote! @JVM If you look at this code the app variable is not re-initializing the app module it's just referencing it.

Comment: I am not sure who gave the down vote. It would work but do we even need the "app" variable in your example?

Comment: @JVM It's more a matter of preference. Regardless of whether it's used or not the code will work.

Comment: Now, I am also curious to know why you got a down vote.